# Permutations with replacement

Tags: matlab, for-loop, permutation, replace

I would like to obtain all the permutations with replacement of d elements chosen in a set of n elements (which are numbers from 0 to n-1) in MATLAB. I noticed that on MATLAB Central the method npermutek is available, but I would like to try another implementation.

My idea is to make d for loops, one inside the other, each varying an index from 0 to n-1: i.e., d recursions over a line (from 0 to n-1). However, n and d should be parameters of my code, so I cannot implement my idea of d for loops one inside the other... or could I? Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use `combn` on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, that code does what I want, but I am a bit disappointed with its name: with combinations, order should not matter. Hence, it is named COMBN but it returns permutations with replacement.

Comment: @Pippo: you *are* free to rename it...And you could suggest this to the author, too.

Comment: Ok, it's true that I'm free to rename it. :) But it is strange that with a code published in 2005, with 26 high ratings, nobody has complained about this. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I use [combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations). Perhaps somebody should run a benchmark to see which implementation is best.